# How to create a clear background Button in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want the text of the button to be black but the button itself to be clear.

All of these variations lead to the same appearance (the default appearance!):

```
Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Click me 0!").backgroundColor(.clear)
        }
        .background(Color.clear)
        .backgroundColor(.clear)
        
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Click me 1!").backgroundColor(.clear)
        }
        .backgroundColor(.clear)
        .background(Color.clear)
        
        
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Click me 0.0!")
        }
        .background(Color.clear)
        .backgroundColor(.clear)
        
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Click me 1!")
        }
        .backgroundColor(.clear)
        .background(Color.clear)
        
        
        Button("click me 2") {
            
        }
        .background(Color.clear)
        .backgroundColor(.clear)
        
        
        Button("click me 3") {
            
        }
        .backgroundColor(.clear).background(Color.clear)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need plain button style, like

```
Button("Demo") {
  // action is here
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())    // << here !!
```